# Serverless error - unsupported function event - Kafka msk

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have the following configuration for serverless Lambda which is supposed to be triggered by a Kafka MSK.

Using Serverless `2.72.2`

Yet when deploying I get the error `event[0] unsupported function event`

```
  kafkaConsumer:
    role: 'some_arn'
    handler: kafkaConsumer.trigger
    name: some-kafka-consumer
    events:
      - msk:
          arn: 'kafka_cluster_arn'
          topic: 'kafka_topic_name'
```

Please advise what I'm not configuring properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you might be using a version of the Framework that does not support `msk` event definition. It was added in `2.3.0` release: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#230-2020-09-25

Comment: Upgraded to serverless 2.72.0, and still getting the same error

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of the bug you're getting, along with detailed output from `sls deploy` command - otherwise it's hard to help and reason about your issue.

Comment: You were correct, after upgrading I discovered an indentation issue which caused the error.

Comment: Great to hear that you've been able to resolve the issue!